# Im trying to make a ascii map using a vector of string vectors, but it isn't working

Tags: c++, vector

Hi im trying to make a small ascii roguelike.
But for the map i want to use vectors(or if there's a better solution i'd love to hear it). 
And the code i tried to use to define such a vector is:
`<vector<string>> test;`
And i also tried to declare a function in a header file like this:
`Map(vector<vector<string> > test;`
But with the declaration of the fuction i keep getting an error, why?
The language i'm using is c++.

```
In file included from Map.cpp:8:0:
Map.h:13:15: error: expected ')' before '<' token
Map(vector<vector<string> > map);
           ^
Map.cpp:10:9: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
Map::Map(vector<vector<string> > map) {
     ^
```

This was the error message i got, and this is the code from the header and class file:

```
#include "Map.h"

Map::Map(vector<vector<string> > map) {
}
```

and this is the header:

```
#ifndef MAP_H
#define MAP_H

class Map {
public:
Map(vector<vector<string> > map);
private:

};

#endif  /* MAP_H */
```

Comment: You have to show us the error message and the code that caused it. Ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is this better?, i don't have a MCVE( and i don't know what this is), but this is what i do have.

Comment: Why do you need a vector of vectors. Am I missing something? If I wanted to build an ascii table using a vector I would use vector of char.

Comment: Not an ascii table, its a 2d map using ascii characters

Comment: Or at least thats what it will be

Comment: You need to `#include <vector>`, and call it by its name,  `std::vector`. Similarly for `string`.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see in your header file where you have included `vector` and `string`. Also when using them you should qualify them with `std::` if the namespace is not available in this scope or by applying `using` to the namespace.